# How do i limit results in a while loop with jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I didn't really know how to set up the question without making it extremely long, so I will explain the thick of it in here.

Basically my code is pulling images from a directory on another server. I am using a jQuery pagination script I found online. The script works, but only after every single image loads on the page (there are a lot of images, so it takes a while to load).

What I'm wanting to accomplish is basically being able to load the page quickly by only showing 36 results at a time. I'd like the jQuery pagination to work, but what'd be even more ideal is just loading is as you scroll down. I've tried using a few different endless scrolling scripts on this, but for some reason it never works properly.

Hopefully I'm making it very clear on what I'm trying to do.

Here is the link to the page: http://habbolicious.com/v2/testing.php

...and here is the code:

```
    <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID : "test",
        perPage: 36
      });
});
</script>
</head>

<div class="holder"></div>
<div id="test">

<?php
$url = "http://habbo.it/gamedata/external_flash_texts/0";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$newlines = array("\n" ,"\r", "\r\n", ">", "<", "/");
$content = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($data));

$Statushtml= '/badge_desc_(.+?)=/';
preg_match_all($Statushtml,$content,$Statusraw);
$badges = implode("-", $Statusraw[0]);
$badgevar = explode("=-badge_desc_", $badges);
$number = ($badgevar);
$badgevar2 = str_replace("=","",$badgevar);
$badgevar3 = str_replace("badge_desc_","",$badgevar2);
$number = count($badgevar3);
while ($number != 0) { ?> 

<script>
$("img").error(function () { 
    $(this).parent().css({display:"none"}); 
});
</script>

<?php

$number = $number - 1; ?>

<?php
$imageUrl = "http://images.habbo.it/c_images/album1584/$badgevar3[$number].gif";
echo '<div class="derpy" style="width:10%; height:70px; line-height:10px; overflow:hidden; border-radius:5px; background:#eaeaea; color:#585858; float:left; margin:5px; padding:10px; text-align:center;"><img class="lazy" src="' . $imageUrl . '" onerror="this.style.display=none" /><br/>' . $badgevar3[$number] . '</div>';
if(file_exists($imageUrl))
{

} else {

}
}
?>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: The keyword is `lazy load`. You'll find plenty of jQuery plugins for that.

Comment: I've tried it already, and with the data that's being pulled it, it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: looks like thousands of images.... get data as json not loading all at once as html...counting json array for pagination is extremely fast. optimize image sizes also

Answer (score 0):

in your script:
$number = count(****);

and the 'while' make a countdown for the $number to the 0.

if you want only 36 pictures, then you need the line 10  "$number = 36;" , instead of "$number = ($badgevar);"